# Single word for ... a man who is polite and kind towards women

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Recently I was talking with one of male *friends*, and he expressed that he would be glad to help me. In response to his kind concern of offering me help, I replied "*You are so gallant*". After a few minutes, when I looked up the dictionary, this is how the word has been defined:

> (of a man) charmingly attentive and chivalrous to women (Adjective).
> a man who is charmingly attentive to women (Noun).

This word seems to misstate my feelings which is *I'm glad that he is ready to offer me help and that doesn't involve any romantic affair*. But *gallant* seems to misrepresent it. I don't see his concern as *charmingly* attractive to me rather it appears to me great words of concern from a good friend. Is there any other single word to express this? For man who is so kind and helpful towards women that doesn't come under romantic affair-one word (Adjective, preferably)?

Comment: I don't think *gallant* necessarily implies romantic intentions. In any case, the idiomatic response is "*Thank you, you're such a gentleman.*"

Comment: Gallant has a heroic aspect to it. It would need to be used light-heartedly, and it would hearten your Galahad. *Gentleman*, on the other hand, does serve to keep any personal involvement at arm's length.

Comment: Galahad-? A gallant seems to be a powerful word!

Comment: You are so ***polite***. You're far more likely to hear that than *you are so Gentlemanly*. But as the above comments say or otherwise hint, *you are such a gentleman* is the idiomatic way to compliment the guy.

Comment: 'Gallant' seems perfectly appropriate. It sounds a bit old-fashioned, but is a reasonable synonym for the situation.

Comment: 'Gallant' here comes across as tongue-in-cheek rather than sexist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with a genderless equivalent, and if you are in North America, I can suggest

***[mensch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mensch)***

> A person of integrity and honour. (origin Yiddish)
>
> (Oxford)

Your situation:

> A friend said he would be glad to help me. In response to his kind offer, I replied, "Thanks for being such a mensch."

Comment: For those not in the know, you might want to add that "mensch" is a Yiddish word.  This is the first word that came to my mind, when I read the question.

Comment: This word is so beautiful as it's meaning.Thanks for sharing this @aparente001 :) *Never heard of this word*

Comment: I would define it as meaning *decent, doing the right thing*.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be considering "charmingly attentive" as equivalent to "romantic". One can be charming and attentive without any romantic intentions too.

In any case, a related and probably more relevant word (appearing multiple times already in this question and responses) is ***chivalrous***.

M-W:

> **[chivalrous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chivalrous)**
>
> *adjective*
>
> **3 b** :  marked by gracious courtesy and high-minded consideration especially to women
>
> A chivalrous man offered the woman his seat on the crowded bus.

Comment: I didn't consider "charmingly attentive" equivalent to "romantic". But the other gender does ;) chivalrous is the Synonym of gallant and it fits well :)

Comment: Did the "other gender" (using your words, not mine) collectively tell you so? if it was only one person, then that person was misinterpreting the word _gallant_.

Comment: Agreed! Also I find both gallant and chivalrous can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

From Google:

> gent·le·man ˈjen(t)lmən/ noun noun: gentleman; plural noun: gentlemen
>
> ```
> 1.
> a chivalrous, courteous, or honorable man.
> "he behaved like a perfect gentleman"
>     a man of good social position, especially one of wealth and leisure.
>     (in the UK) a man of noble birth attached to a royal household.
>     synonyms: man; More
>     nobleman;
>     informalgent;
>     archaiccavalier
>     "a fine steed suitable for a gentleman such as yourself"
> 2.
> a polite or formal way of referring to a man.
> "opposite her an old gentleman sat reading"
> ```
>
> gen·tle·man·ly
>
> ˈjen(t)lmənlē/ adjective adjective: gentlemanly
>
> ```
> (of a man) befitting a gentleman; chivalrous, courteous, or honorable.
> "a paragon of gentlemanly conduct"
> synonyms: chivalrous, gallant, honorable, noble, courteous, civil, mannerly, polite, gracious, considerate, thoughtful; well bred,
> ```
>
> cultivated, cultured, refined, suave, urbane
>       "gentlemanly manners came naturally to him"

Comment: You mean? That's so gentle man of you?  I'm looking for an adjective @Xanne. not a noun :)  just Edited the question.

Comment: I added the adjective to the answer

Comment: *Gentlemanly* may exist  but it smacks of being literary or poetic to me. I don't think many native speakers would use it in everyday English. And people are far more likely to say something such as *you are so polite* if they stray from the idiomatic *you're such a gentleman*.

Comment: Well, perhaps someone will come up with something better.  "Brotherly" might be a possibility.

Comment: @Xanne lol. Brotherly, why dude? It's like 'Dude,you're so kind to help. Let me brother zone you' ?!  Polite seems to be more appropriate and gallant,now I realise is too powerful to be used in my provided case.